# Marathon (Mesos) - Stuck in "Loading applications"

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

I am building a mesos cluster from scratch (using Vagrant, which is not relevant for this issue).
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 (trusty)
Setup:

- Master -> Runs ZooKeeper, Mesos-master, Marathon and Chronos
- Slave -> Runs Mesos-slave

This is my provisioning script for the master node https://github.com/zeitgeist2018/infrastructure/blob/fix-marathon/provision/scripts/install-master.sh.

I have managed to register de slave into Mesos, install Marathon and Chronos frameworks, and run scheduled jobs in Chronos (both with docker and shell commands), but I can't get Marathon to work properly. The UI gets stuck in "Loading applications" as soon as I open it, and when I try to call the API, the request hangs forever with no response. In the API I tried to get simple marathon information and do deployments, both with the same hanging result.
I've been checking Marathon logs but I don't see anything error there. Just a couple of logs that may (or not) be a hint:

```
[2020-03-08 10:33:21,819] INFO  Prompting Mesos for a heartbeat via explicit task reconciliation (mesosphere.marathon.core.heartbeat.MesosHeartbeatMonitor$$anon$1:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6)
[2020-03-08 10:33:21,822] INFO  Received fake heartbeat task-status update (mesosphere.marathon.core.heartbeat.MesosHeartbeatMonitor:Thread-87)
[2020-03-08 10:33:25,957] INFO  Found no roles suitable for revive repetition. (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.ReviveOffersStreamLogic$ReviveRepeaterLogic:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share more logs and output from `/v2/app` and `/info`?

Comment: I already fixed the issue, you can see it in my answer below

Comment: Downgrading is not a fix. You may miss important updates in the future

Comment: I agree, but since this cluster I'm building is just for fun and downgrading makes it work, I consider it a fix. Anyway, what do you have in mind in order to fix the actual issue?

Comment: Check `/v2/apps` endpoint if you can see your app there then inspect UI in browser and check network tab, I think something is blocking UI from getting responses from server.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, I tried to call the API directly, but it just hangs forever, not even giving an error, that's why I'm a bit lost and can't find any hint.

Comment: Can you share more logs?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Comment: Not yet. I have this project stopped for some time while I'm working on other things. If not using the very latest version is not an issue for you, just downgrade it.

Answer (score 2):

Installing **jdk11** and choosing it as default fixed this issue for me without downgrading the Marathon to any other version.

in ubuntu 20.04:

```sh
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 1):

I increased the number of cpus, virtual machine in which the marathon was installed to 3 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work. It was as simple as downgrading Marathon to `v1.7.189`. After that, it starts properly, and the API responds to requests.